# Docker compose for node server fails

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I wrote a node server that runs via npm script (npm run dev).
I created the following Dockerfile for it:

```
FROM node:10.12.0

ARG COMMIT_REF
ARG BUILD_DATE

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV APP_COMMIT_REF=${COMMIT_REF} \
    APP_BUILD_DATE=${BUILD_DATE}

ENV PORT 8009

EXPOSE 8009

CMD [ "npm", "run", "server" ]
```

Building and running the server with:
`docker build . -t server` and `docker run -it -p 8009:8009 --env-file .env server` works great and the server runs and exposed on port 8009.

Noe I try to create `docker-compose.yml` for it. This is what I wrote:

```
version: '3'

services:
    server:
        image: server
        build: .
        env_file:
            - .env
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        working_dir: /.
        ports:
            - 8009:8009
```

When I run it using `docker-compose up` I get:

```
Starting bed_server_1 ... done
Attaching to bed_server_1
server_1  | npm ERR! path /package.json
server_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
server_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
server_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
server_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
server_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
server_1  | npm ERR! enoent
server_1  |
server_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
server_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-04T22_27_50_916Z-debug.log
bed_server_1 exited with code 254
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image's CMD runs `npm run server` in whatever directory it starts up in.  The `docker-compose.yml` `working_dir: /` tells the container to start up in the root directory.  That's not what you want; you want the container to start up in the directory you COPY'd its source code to.

You will probably fix your immediate issue if you remove the `working_dir:` line.